# how to get a formatted text output with no html tags (in symfony)?

Tags: php, symfony1, tinymce

I'm working on a first symfony project, i am using the sfWidgetFormTextareaTinyMCE widget for a form tinymce text area. It works fine, but while retrieving from database, instead of showing me the formated text, i have the `<strong>,<p>,<br>`tags in the text. help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [output escaping](http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_output_escaping) turned on in your application.  To avoid it for that specific output you can use the `$sf_data->getRaw()` method available in your templates like this:

```
<?php echo $sf_data->getRaw('html'); ?>
```

That is assuming that the raw HTML you wanted to display is stored in $html within the template by your action:

```
$this->html = $object->getHtml();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: when i am using this.. i am getting this below error.

Notice: Undefined index: html in lib\vendor\symfony\lib\escaper\sfOutputEscaperArrayDecorator.class.php on line 174

what to do with this??  please help.. thanks in advance

Comment: @vesselyp Your value is most likely not stored in a variable called 'html', you should change the string to match the name of the variable that the value is stored in.  I store the value in 'html' by using '$this->html = ""' which is why I reference 'html'.